# bear oneself out

Tags: idioms, reflexives

This is part of a TED talk "[How the blockchain will radically transform the economy](https://www.ted.com/talks/bettina_warburg_how_the_blockchain_will_radically_transform_the_economy/transcript?utm_campaign=Insights&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-_688JpJ871bng6RBmvz8Ltivb-sQZYqcUsF8KGYIrYsI1Rn6EVcZcbSGmeMkfRBSgMEr3HOnlntMbOkH6kPV-4mmY4OQ#t-549076)":

> The last uncertainty that we often face is one of the most open-ended,
>   and it's reneging. What if you don't send me the smartphone? Can I get
>   my money back? Blockchains allow us to write code, binding contracts,
>   between individuals and then guarantee that those contracts will **bear**
>   **out** without a third party enforcer.

In the last sentence, 'bear out' seems to have no object.

Can you say "bear themselves out" instead here?

> ...and then guarantee that those contracts will **bear themselves out** without a third party enforcer.

Comment: 'Bear out' means, here, 'be fulfilled'. The concept (whatever words are chosen to clothe it) is a passive concept so has no object.

Comment: Nigel, +1 for the cleverly clad joke.

Comment: @NigelJ _Bear something out_ is defined in Oxford as "Support or confirm something," as in _this assumption is not borne out by any evidence_ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bear_something_out Then, where did you get the idea of the intransitive _bear out_ meaning 'be fulfilled'?

Comment: @JK2 'bear out without a third party enforcer' implies the successful fulfilment of the contract, to me.

Comment: @NigelJ So the 'bear out' in the TED talk has nothing to do with the phrase defined in Oxford?

Comment: @JK2 did you ask your Question because you were or were not sure of the answer? Nigel's response was wholly correct. Do you not accept 'be fulfilled' as much more than not identical to "Support or confirm"?

Either way in your book, is there great similarity among “bear out” and “bear oneself out” and “bear themselves out”?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Which of NigelJ's responses are you referring to when you said it was "wholly correct"? All of them? My question hinges on the fact that no dictionary I know of shows an intransitive use of 'bear out'. And NigelJ seems to say in his first comment that it's even natural for 'bear out' to be used intransitively. On top of that, he claims that there is another meaning of the phrase, namely, 'be fulfilled', which can anything but 'support or confirm (something)'.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If you 100% agree with NigelJ, could you provide me with some authoritative source such as dictionaries that shows that 'bear out' is indeed in use intransitively, and that its meaning can be 'be fulfilled'? Better yet, if you can do that, I suggest you write an answer for me.

Comment: No, thanks… If I could be bothered with that I'd have written an Answer with citations.

Again in your book, is there significant  similarity among “bear out” and “bear oneself out” and “bear themselves out”?

You're welcome and for myself, I'm not sure "bear themselves out" belongs in English Language Learners, let alone ELU?